# counting jquery ui drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to create a drag and drop box using jQuery UI. I also have an input/ submit button, such that whenever I click on the button the count increases. If the box is dropped, the count can be 1 or else it becomes 0.

This code is not working:

```js
 $(function() {
   var count = 0;
   $("#draggable").draggable();
   $("#droppable").droppable({
     drop: function(event, ui) {
       //  var draggable = ui.draggable;
       // alert('The square with ID "' + draggable.attr('id') + '" was dropped onto me!');
       if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass("draggable")) {
         $(this)
           .find("p")
           .html("Correct!");
         count++;
         $(".counttext").text("There are " + count + " divs inside parent box detail.");
         if (count == 2) {
           alert("You got them all right!");
         }
       } else {
         $(this)
           .find("p")
           .html("Wrong!");
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: the code is not running.Only i can drag and drop the box.I want some count as well

Comment: Do you see any errors in your Console? Can you use jsfiddle.net and create a working example of the issue? there is not enough for us to determine the issue or what is not working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JRLZK/2/

Comment: just have  a look at the figure.It is similar to my code.Here the statement ''There are 0 divs inside parent box detail.'' should change to 1,2 3 as we drag and drop the boxes

Comment: You have: `var div = $("<div />");` but then you never append this `div` to the document. Also your `$.each()` is only executed when the page loads, so the count would only ever show 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to accomplish what you're trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ttyt320c/

**JQuery**

```
var foodCount = 0;

$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
  $(".wrong").draggable();
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("Accepting object.");
      ui.draggable.draggable("destroy");
      if (ui.draggable.attr("class") === "draggable") {
        foodCount++;
        console.log("Count: " + foodCount);
        $(".count").text(foodCount);
        alert('correct');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

In the `drop`, we only want to accept a specific object. This can be used other ways later if needed, such as reverting the object. We check the `class` of the dropped object. If it's `draggable` we update the count and remove the `draggable()` ability so it cannot be moved.